# How to make a portion of an UIImageView transparent in order to show views in layers below

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, transparency

Here is a photo explanation to better illustrate what I mean:

I have two `UIImageViews`, with `View1` being on the bottom and `View2` at the top:

[image] [image]

What I would like to do accomplish is to programmatically set an area on `View2` that is completely transparent (i.e. has an `alpha` of `0`), so that this will be the end result:

[image]

I haven't been able to find a similar problem related to marking a part of a UIImageView transparent in the form of a shape (specifically, a circle), and was wondering how I should tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One road you could go is CoreGraphics:

1. Create an image context
2. Set the clipping path you need (or just clear the circle for the "hole" after drawing)
3. Draw the original image into the context
4. Make an UIImage from that context
5. Assign the image to the top UIImageView

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW1

Comment: Thanks for answering and the suggestion @iOSX. I'll have a look at the documentation and see if I could figure out a way to get the "hole" to work with the clipping path as suggested.